# linear combination vectors into one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

write $x(a_1,a_2,a_3)+y(b_1,b_2,b_3)+z(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ as

$Y(a_1,a_2,a_3,$

$b_1,b_2,b_3, $

$c_1,c_2,c_3)$

^as a 3x3 matrix

for a suitable Y?

Answer (score 0):

Combining those three vectors gives $$(xa_1+yb_1+zc_1, xa_2+yb_2+zc_2, xa_3+yb_3+zc_3)$$